# Converting xml selection to a number in JSP

Tags: java, xml, jsp

I have the following xml in a file

```
<knowledgecases>
<knowledgecase>
<caseid>101000000009</caseid> 
<question>What can I put into my brown bin?</question> 
<version /> 
</knowledgecase>
<knowledgecase>
<caseid>101000000006</caseid> 
<question>What is ‘Scores on the Doors’?</question> 
<version /> 
</knowledgecase>
</knowledgecases>
```

I am trying to add 1 to the caseids.

So I have tried this

```
<c:import var="xml" url="<%=theUrl%>">
<c:param name="param1" value="${param.param1}"/>
<c:param name="param2" value="${param.param2}"/>
</c:import>
<body>
<x:parse xml="${xml}" var="output"/>
<ul class="list">
<x:forEach select="$output/knowledgecases/knowledgecase/caseid" var="newcaseid">
<c:set var="count" value="${newcaseid + 1}"/>
<li>adjacent case <x:out select="$count" /></li>
</x:forEach>
</ul>
</body>
```

I want it to display

`101000000010`

`101000000007`

Instead I get the error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert [caseid: null] of type class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementNSImpl to Number
```

If I change

```
value="${newcaseid + 1} to value="${newcaseid}
```

it displays

`101000000009`

`101000000006`

Don't know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `newcaseid` var is a [org.w3c.dom.Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html), and can not be used directly in Expression language. You have to transform it first to something that EL can use (a Number or a String).

You can make it work like this:

```
<x:parse xml="${xml}" var="output"/>
<ul class="list">
  <x:forEach select="$output/knowledgecases/knowledgecase/caseid" var="newcaseid">
     <c:set var="current"><x:out select="$newcaseid"/></c:set>
     <li>adjacent case <c:out value="${current + 1}" /></li>
  </x:forEach>
</ul>
```